# Make tailwind favor rgba() instead of rgb(/var(--tw-text-opacity))

Tags: tailwind-css

My iOS device is older, so in Safari some colors are not showing. I don't know why, but I'm guessing it's due to how tailwind is setting text-color or background-color to use `rgb` but with a `/opacity-value` for instance:

Using `class="text-blue-600"` creates this CSS to be applied:

```
.text-blue-600 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1 !important;
  color: rgb(37 99 235/var(--tw-text-opacity)) !important;
}
```

[image]

Or doing `class="bg-gray-200"` causes this CSS to be applied:

```
.bg-gray-200 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(229 231 235/var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```

[image]

I wanted to test if this is what's breaking the CSS on old Safari on iOS 10. Is there a way to tell tailwind to use `rgba` which I think should be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tailwind will use this syntax when the [background opacity utilities](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/background-opacity) are enabled.

You can disable this by adding this to your `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
  // tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    corePlugins: {
      // ...

     backgroundOpacity: false,
    }
  }
```

In my case, I had a similar issue with text and border colors. You might need to experiment and figure out which of these "opacity" utilities are causing you trouble. For my project, I disabled all of them:

```js
  // tailwind.config.js
  module.exports = {
    corePlugins: {
      // ...
        backdropOpacity: false,
        backgroundOpacity: false,
        borderOpacity: false,
        divideOpacity: false,
        ringOpacity: false,
        textOpacity: false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I also heard it's possible to use postcss to do accomplish this without losing the opacity feature? But I can't figure that out

Comment: I tried using https://github.com/dmarchena/postcss-color-rgb but it didn't seem to work. I think it doesn't catch the syntax tailwind is using because of the css variables. You could try updating the plugin and seeing if you can get it to work. 

Comment: Thanks I also tried the same one but had no luck :( Really appreciate your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

You can use postcss and postcss-preset-env plugin,  Its will convert rgb to rgba by default

Comment: Thanks! The github repo for this says its archived, is there a maintained version of it? https://github.com/csstools/postcss-preset-env

Comment: @Noitidart    I find  maintained version  in here  https://github.com/csstools/postcss-plugins/tree/main/plugin-packs/postcss-preset-env